# What is the best capacity for a Production use DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am using an application in production. I need to know what is the best capacity to put in read and write. Right now I see it is millions in both read and write? And also what is the best for a huge usage, is `On-Demand` or `Provisioned Capacity`? Right now I am using `On-Demand` mode but in production when we have a lot of traffic what will be the best way? Will Provisioned Capacity is cheaper? Or good to continue with On-Demand mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start with `On-Demand`, which will usually be cheapest and ensure you don't pay extra for capacity you don't use.

After running in production for a few weeks, you can look at the DynamoDB read/write metrics and decide on `Provisioned Capacity` settings which make sense for your app, and may save you money. You'll need to revisit this as your app usage grows, along with monitor for read/write throttling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.